# How to generate barcode with ionic+cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, barcode, generated-code

I have one problem. I use phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner. Scan work perfect but generator barcode doesn't work? When I press button to encoding my app crashing and have error "unfortunately app has stopped". Please help me)

Comment: Sounds like a problem with that plugin and not directly a question on which we can help. If you need further help, provide some code - especially the code from your encode function and where it is called.

Comment: How can we help out with out giving any lines of code?